# Repeated error "The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed."

Tags: windows-10, networking, windows-domain

I have a user whose laptop keeps throwing up the "The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed" error message every time she unplugs it from the Ethernet. Also sometimes when she doesn't. We've fixed it a couple of times by disconnecting from the domain and reconnecting, but it keeps happening. Through some combination of unplugging the ethernet and restarting the computer, it will usually fix itself. Any ideas of what's happening?

Comment: Is this the only computer which does that? Might you have duplicate computer names on the domain? Is the computer's clock always correct?

Answer (score 1):

Without further information, the error is an indication of an issue with synchronization of the machine account password in Active Directory.

There are some good tips on this thread [SuperUser - Trust Relationship Failing](https://superuser.com/questions/947750/how-can-i-get-the-trust-relationship-to-the-domain-to-stop-failing?rq=1).

The quickest validation is to ensure your time is being synchronized appropriately in Active Directory, and on the client computer.

> If we have only one domain:
>
> 1. PDC emulator with FSMO roles synchronizes its time with an external NTP time server (could be clock device, a router, another standalone
>    server, an internet time server…).
> 2. DCs synchronize their time with PDC emulator.
> 3. All member servers and workstations synchronize their time with any domain controller.

> [Microsoft TechNet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2b7a966b-ccc1-48b7-93d0-4b6973b82403/the-trust-relationship-between-this-workstation-and-the-primary-domain-failed?forum=winserverDS)

If the time is OK, you can try to reset the machine account with the following line in Powershell. Replace *PSCredential* with a Domain Admin account, and *String* with a Domain Controller. You can also perform this by going to the machine account in Active Directory Users and Computers, right clicking the computer name, and hit Reset Account.

```powershell
    # The syntax
    Reset-ComputerMachinePassword [-Credential <PSCredential>] [-Server <String>]
    
    # An Example
    Reset-ComputerMachinePassword -Credential domain.local\admin -Server DC01
```

> [Noel Alvarez](https://noelalvarez.net/microsoft-active-directory-trust-relationship-failure-with-primary-domain/)

You should be required to rejoin the computer to the domain after performing the reset.

If none of those methods work, you can try to completely remove existence of that computer on the domain before rejoining it:

> 1. Unjoin the computer from the domain
> 2. Remove the machine account from Users and Computers
> 3. Rejoin the computer to the domain

Make sure to go through the proper reboots after each step on the client. If you have multiple domain controllers, you may want to ensure the changes replicated to all relevant domain controllers before rejoining the computer to the domain.

Answer (score 0):

1. Verify user is on correct internal NTP server(s).  This causes many such issues
2. Run command NBTSTAT -RR
3. Remove from domain, delete from AD if orphaned in AD, confirm no duplicates or orphaned exist and that no DNS or DHCP leases are present.
4. Reboot and rejoin to domain
5. Run all updates on client and if possible on all Domain Controllers as well

Good luck.