# Re-joining a computer to domain when cache credential and local administrator are disabled

Tags: windows-7, login, domain

I have a problem with a Windows 7 PC that had been a member of the domain. When I try to logon to this PC with domain credentials I get a message similar to

```
The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain could not be established.
```

I read [this link](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1521495-trust-relationship-lost-and-no-local-admin-account-possible-to-fix-remotely), however, I have some issues.

**issues:**
1. There are no active local accounts on the machine that I could use to logon and the local administrator disabled via group policy.
2. The credential cache logon disabled (set to zero) via group policy.

So I can't log in with the local administrator to rejoin the domain.
How can I re-trust PC and domain?

Edit:
I saw [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/555297/re-joining-a-computer-to-domain) and Reset Account in AD but this way isn't useful for my problem.

Comment: Questions: (1) Is the PC within the AD network, and can it see the domain server? (2) Can you join using another domain account? (3) Try the troubleshooting methods in [this post](https://appuals.com/fix-trust-relationship-workstation-primary-domain-failed/) and especially Method 3. Since you cannot login, you may still gain admin access by using the [Utilman.exe Trick](https://www.technibble.com/bypass-windows-logons-utilman/).

Comment: Did you re-add the PC to the domain on the Server side?

Comment: @Moab, Yes, however, It hasn't worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to activate local admin account following the next guide - https://www.howtogeek.com/75470/how-to-enable-the-hidden-windows-7-admin-account-using-the-registry/

After that, just rejoin domain

Comment: That's a great trick.